# Не получается ничего установить при помощи apt install в ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

При любом запросе типа "sudo apt-get install *** " начинается процесс установки, но при распаковке выбрасывает ошибку, после которой некоторые пакеты устанавливаются и работают исправно, какие-то работают не исправно, а какие-то не отображаются как установленные.

```
dpkg: error processing package openmpi-bin (--configure):
 installed openmpi-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mpi-default-bin:
 mpi-default-bin depends on openmpi-bin; however:
  Package openmpi-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mpi-default-bin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64:
 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64 depends on openmpi-bin; however:
  Package openmpi-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libopenmpi-dev:amd64:
 libopenmpi-dev:amd64 depends on openmpi-bin (>= 3.0.0-1); however:
  Package openmpi-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libopenmpi-dev:amd64 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-mpi-python1.74.0:
 libboost-mpi-python1.74.0 depends on mpi-defauNo apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
           No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                                       No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                           No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                                                               lt-bin; however:
  Package mpi-default-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libboost-mpi-python1.74.0 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev:
 libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev depends on libboost-mpi-python1.74.0 (= 1.74.0-14ubuntu3); however:
  Package libboost-mpi-python1.74.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-mpi-python-dev:
 libboost-mpi-python-dev depends on libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev; however:
  Package libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libboost-mpi-python-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-all-dev:
 libboost-all-dev depends on libboost-mpi-python-dev; however:
  PackageNo apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                             No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
 No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                      libboost-mpi-python-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libboost-all-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mpi-default-dev:
 mpi-default-dev depends on libopenmpi-dev; however:
  Package libopenmpi-dev:amd64 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mpi-default-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-mpi1.74-dev:
 libboost-mpi1.74-dev depends on mpi-default-dev; however:
  Package mpi-default-dev is not configured yet.

No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                                                                                        dpkg: error processing package libboost-mpi1.74-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of libboost-mpi-dev:
 libboost-mpi-dev depends on libboost-mpi1.74-dev; however:
  Package libboost-mpi1.74-dev is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package libboost-mpi-dev (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because MaxReports has already been reached
                                                                    Errors were encountered while processing:
 openmpi-bin
 mpi-default-bin
 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64
 libopenmpi-dev:amd64
 libboost-mpi-python1.74.0
 libboost-mpi-python1.74-dev
 libboost-mpi-python-dev
 libboost-all-dev
 mpi-default-dev
 libboost-mpi1.74-dev
 libboost-mpi-dev
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Пробовал всё от apt update до перезапуска.
Что можно сделать чтобы пропала эта ошибка и пакеты исправно устанавивались?

Answer (score 2):

Почистите кэш APT и базу данных пакетов с исправлением битых:

```
sudo apt clean
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt -f install
```

Удалите ваш проблемный пакет и попробуйте переустановить его:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq openmpi-bin
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openmpi-bin
```

Потом

```
sudo apt autoremove
```

И пожалуй

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```

Comment: Такое же исключение бросается на любую из этих инструкций...

Comment: dpkg: dependency problems prevent removal of openmpi-bin:
 mpi-default-bin depends on openmpi-bin.
 libopenmpi-dev:amd64 depends on openmpi-bin (>= 3.0.0-1).
 libcoarrays-openmpi-dev:amd64 depends on openmpi-bin.

dpkg: error processing package openmpi-bin (--remove):
 dependency problems - not removing
Errors were encountered while processing:
 openmpi-bin